# How to find/configure/setup Windows 8 SMTP Server

Tags: windows-8

- it sounds silly i know but where is SMTP services in Windows 8 and i've searched for hrs on this.  I notice Windows 8 IIS 8 no longer has SMTP services in the gui.  Does anyone know what has replaced/augmented these services in Windows 8.  I have searched and searched on the web and i can't find anything substancial on this at all.

I'm looking for whatever the native MS application is for Windows 8 to support SMTP mail.

Comment: Seriously... this is getting downed???? Really????  It is not a component of IIS anymore and there is no documentation about SMTP server support for Windows 8.  Look for yourselves folks.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft SMTP/e-mail system is called Microsoft Exchange, and requires a separate licence to be purchased. If you have purchased the licence, there are download and installation instructions on the card your CoA is stuck to.

IIS (Internet Information Services) is the Microsoft web/HTTP server that comes bundled with most server versions of Windows, and has nothing to do with SMTP (though it is required for Exchange to function propperly.)

Comment: Not true - there is a SMTP server in IIS 6 which is not related to Exchange Server http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/e4cf06f5-9a36-474b-ba78-3f287a2b88f2.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: SMTP doesn't have to do with IIS, in the case that you state, SMPT is accessible via the IIS UI, but has been removed since.

Answer (score 1):

I see there is a step-by-step description of how to enable SMTP in Windows 8 shown here:
http://www.neatcomponents.com/enable-SMTP-in-Windows-8

It is clearly part of some support documentation for the neatComponents web development platform but it seems to answer your question pretty directly.

They are drawing a distinction between SMTP service and server, though. HTH

Comment: As it says in your link: `Note - this is an SMTP Service not Server. Emails must be sent to an operational SMTP Server for onward delivery.` The OP question is not clear, as his title states 'server', but his body states 'service'. AFAIK Windows 7 doesn't come with an SMTP server. But Windows Server 2008 and 2013 do. I don't know about Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

The SMTP service is normally added and enabled by default during the installation of neatComponents, and no further action is required.

Enable the SMTP in Windows 8 Pro

1 - Open the Windows Control Panel and select 'Programs & Features'

2 - In Programs & Features select 'Turn Windows Features on and off' in the left column.

3 - You will already have enabled the IIS services to enable the neatComponents installation, but if you have not done so already do that now.

Enable SMTP on Windows 7 & Windows 8

4 - Also enable the ASP.NET services - Windows may ask to get more files from the Internet - accept.

Enable SMTP on Windows 7 & Windows 8

When the feature additions complete you will be able to access the IIS SMTP control from the Windows Control Panel - Administrative Tools.

Note - this is an SMTP Service not Server. Emails must be sent to an operational SMTP Server for onward delivery. Suitable Windows Email Server Software is Mailtraq (fully supported), your ISP's mail server or Microsoft's Exchange Server.

Windows 7

A similar procedure is also used to enable SMTP in Windows 7. SMTP isn't included in Windows 7 by default. But you can install Remote Server Administration Tools that includes SMTP Server Tools for Windows 7 computers that are running the Enterprise, Professional, or Ultimate editions of Windows 7 or Windows 7 with SP1.

Enable SMTP in Windows 2008 and 2012

Details show Windows 2008. A similar procedure is also used to enable  SMTP in W2012

1 - You need to ensure that the IIS Role is operational.

neatComponents enables IIS as part of the installation procedure. It is not normally necessary to make adjustments to this role.

If Web Server (IIS) is not present in the Windows Server Manager, select 'Add Roles'

Enable SMTP in Windows 2008 2012 Server

2 - At the Add Roles Wizard, select Web Server (IIS) and follow the Wizard.

Enable SMTP in Windows 2008 2012 Server

3 - When the wizard completes you can access the IIS Manager from Windows Control Panel, Administrative tools.

In the 'Web Server - IIS' Role Services dialog, add in (install by selecting and then Add) the ASP.NET Role Service indicated below - Windows may ask to get more files from the Internet - accept.

Restart the server. You should then see the SMTP service shown - see below.

Enable SMTP in Windows 2008 2012 Server

Note - this is an SMTP Service not Server. Emails must be sent to an operational SMTP Server for onward delivery.

Suitable mail servers are:

Your ISP's mail server (configure like Outlook)

Dedicated Windows Email Server Software such as  Mailtraq (fully supported),

or Microsoft's Exchange Server.